# I think I deleted my data in SQL

Tags: mysql

I had a table of some 30,000 records in mysql workbench.  All was fine until I ran this query :

```
select case when Breach = 'True' then 1
            when Breach = 'False' then 0
       else 'NN'
       end as val   
from evictions.evictions_sf
```

Was only trying to replace boolean values w/ 1 or 0.  Now, my table is reading all null - see image.

Comment: A SELECT statement by itself isn't going to change any values in your database. Also, you don't have records in Mysql Workbench. You have records in MySQL. Workbench is just a tool for working with MySQL.

Comment: You can stay calm, just by `select`ing you're not going to delete any actual data.

Comment: I'm curious what the `image` is though...

Comment: SELECT cannot change or delete data. It merely chooses (*SELECT*s) data.

Comment: @JNevill Maybe a picture of a computer on fire.

Comment: @tadman pretty sure that wouldn't even "read `null`" then, eh.. On a more serious note @DiamondJoe12, would be nice if it was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51731975/edit) into the question

Comment: Perhaps there was no data in there to begin with? We are all 100000% sure that your `SELECT` statement didn't alter your table because it can't. Did you sneak in a `TRUNCATE` or `DELETE` or `DROP` when you weren't looking?

Comment: Voting to close as a "Problem that can no longer be reproduced" as OP has mentioned in the comments to the answer below that a "Refresh" now shows the data. All is well.

Comment: This question should be deleted as well as there is an answer that really is a comment and offers no real insight to the problem at hand

Comment: I wish I could say this is resolved but unfortunately not.  I thought I had the data back but I do not.   I'm just going to rebuild the database.  Somehow, the data was replaced with 'null' and I've not yet found a solution.   I will backup from now on, and I may start a new thread with what best practice is for backing up.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try a

```
SELECT * from evictions.evictions_sf;
```

If records show up it's all good.  You cannot delete or alter data with a SELECT.

Comment: I'm trying to decide if this is an answer or just a comment

Comment: @JohnConde: It's a comment.

Comment: It's impossible to delete data with `SELECT`. It is possible for someone else to have done something, or for you to have run more than one query. This is a good time to check that you have an effective **backup and restore strategy** if this is critical data.

Comment: This is so odd.  When i use SELECT * FROM evictions.evictions_sf; 'null' is listed under each column.  My query seems to have unequivocally deleted my data.

Comment: It most definitely did not delete your data though. There are centuries of combined SQL expertise commenting on this question and we can all agree that your SELECT statement had no affect on the data in the table. How do you know that there were 30000 records in there to begin with? Have you used more than one client? Is there more than one database with the same table and you are confusing them? Is there more than one server? Have you run anything else recently that would have dropped the records? Are you sure?

Comment: I hit refresh.. and the data re-appeared.   Apologies for being such a bozo.  Thanks for the help and reassurance.

Comment: WONDERFUL! I'm VERY glad to hear that you found them :) I know the panic all too well.